# Pseudo perplexing puzzle in Puzzlopia

Tags: chess, mazes

*Puzzlopia is the site, from where I got this puzzle.*

A chess maze - the name tells it all - you have to move the green horse, to the yellow spot. But hey, you're a peaceful horse, so you don't attack others; but the other red stuff are not peaceful, so they may attack you. Be aware.

[image]

I, the owner of the horse, is a stupid guy. So, instead of moving forward, I decided to backtrack from the solution:

> [image]

Unless I made a dumb mistake, I think it's impossible to reach the green areas (last and penultimate, and meta, and metameta penultimate moves from the outside). Where I am doing it wrong?

(Anybody with a Google, and a working internet can confirm this is not from an ongoing competition.)

Comment: Hm. Don't the other pieces move while you are moving?

Comment: I interpreted "you don't attack others" to mean that you could not move to a spot that would allow you to take another piece on the following turn. Given the solution, I now expect "you don't attack others" simply means that you do not take any of the chess pieces, but moving to a position where you could take one is acceptable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You missed that

> one of the black knights, the one on g5 shields one square (h5) from the black rook. So the white knight can travel there.

Here is the complete solution:

> [image]

Comment: Nobody forces you to hover over the spoilers :)